# Which fields have no extensions of degree divisble by a fixed prime?

Tags: galois-theory, fields, absolute-galois-group

Let $p$ be a prime. What are the most general examples of a field $K$ such that for any finite extension $L/K$ the degree $[L:K]$ is prime to $p$?

Certainly, there are algebraically closed examples an fields whose absolute Galois group consists of $2$ elements (if $p\neq 2$; does there exist a classification of fields of this sort?). More generally,  one may start with a $k$ whose absolute Galois group is abelian and take $K$ being the maximal ind-$p$-extension of $k$. So, can one classify fields with abelian Galois groups (my ideas: finite and quais-finite fields, $l((t))$ for $l$ being algebraically closed, and their ultraproducts)? Do there exists any fields of the sort I want with non-abelian Galois groups?

Comment: Take a prime $l\neq p$ and take an  $l$-Sylow subgroup $H$ of $Gal (\mathbb Q)$. Take $K$ to be the subfield of the algebraic closure of $ \mathbb Q$ which is point-wise fixed by $H$. Then the only Galois  extensions of $K$ are $l$-groups and hence this $K$ works (The $l$-Sylow group $H$ is nonabelian)

Comment: Regarding your question about fields whose absolute Galois group has order $2$; by the Artin-Schreier theorem these are precisely the real closed fields. Anyway, as far as I can tell your question is pretty close to asking which profinite groups have only finite quotients which are prime to $p$ and it doesn't seem like very much can be said at this level of generality.